# Which version of dplyr that is compatible with GLIBCXX_3.4.19 or older?

Tags: r, dplyr, rhel7

```
library(dplyr)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in dyn.load(file,
>   DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>       unable to load shared object '/home/user_name/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/bindrcpp/libs/bindrcpp.so':
>       /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by
>   /home/user_name/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/bindrcpp/libs/bindrcpp.so)

So the problem is that I am running on rhel 7 vms and it is running glibc 3.4.19 ... we cannot install 3.4.21 onto the system because it may break lots of stuff (https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=63033). We are much better off finding versions (older) of bindrcpp and dplyr that work with glibc 3.4.19. Where can I find an older versions of those packages that are compatible with our rhel 7 distribution? Thanks!

Comment: You keep referencing GLIBC, but your problem has *nothing* to do with GLIBC -- it's *all* about `libstdc++`.

Comment: We solved this issue by installing an earlier version of dplyr.